# Paused Sound automatically resumes after Screen.show()

Tags: libgdx, soundpool

I have a sound which is started with a loop method. When I temporarily exit the game by pressing the HOME button the game calls a pause method that  pauses this sound. When I re-enter the current instance of the game the sound **should not** resume automatically because I do that in the click button event method of my Pause Menu; the problem is that it does resume automatically even though the resume method for this sound is not called. why does this happen? what am I missing?

This only happens on the phone not on desktop. If I click outside the DesktopLauncher window and then return to the game I don't hear the sound playing.

Comment: In your show() method just add a check to see if the sound is not null and then pause the sound.